# Javascript map is not a function what trying to read data

Tags: javascript, data-structures, iteration, reduce

I am trying to populate a chart so I'm getting the data into 2 lists in order to do this.

This is the data:

```
var data = [{
    "id": "622",
    "name": "some name",
    "boats": {
        "637": {
            "id": "637",
            "name": " Subcat 1",
            "translations": null
        },
        "638": {
            "id": "638",
            "name": "Subcat 2",
            "translations": null
        }
    },
    "image": "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6286b"
}];
```

And I am running this code in order to populate the lists:

```
var chList = [];
var boatList = [];
var boatCount = [];


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var obj = data[i];

    var cl = obj.name + " [" + obj.id + "]";

    if (obj.boats != null) {
        chList.push(cl);
    }

    if(obj.boats) {

        var nme = obj.boats.map( function(item){
            return item.name;
        });

        boatList = boatList.concat(nme);
        boatCount.push(nme.length);

    }

}

console.log(boatList);
console.log(boatCount);
```

My problem is that I keep getting:

TypeError: obj.boats.map is not a function

How can I fix this?

**Note: The data is actually this:**

```
{
    "id": "622",
    "name": "some name",
    "boats": {
        "637": {
            "id": "637",
            "name": " Subcat 1",
            "translations": null
        },
        "638": {
            "id": "638",
            "name": "Subcat 2",
            "translations": null
        }
    },
    "image": "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6286b"
};
```

But I added [ and ] to it in order to use data.length and the lists where empty too ... Do I then leave this data as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `obj.boats` is an object, not an array, hence doesn't have the `map` method.

Try this instead:

```
Object.keys(obj.boats).map(function(k) { return obj.boats[k].name; });
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I've added a note to the question that might me important

Comment: ES6: Object.keys(obj.boats).map(k => obj.boats[k].name)

Answer (score 0):

`boats` is an object, not an array. Map is for arrays.

You could use a `for ( in )` loop or `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys and work with that.

Comment: I've added a note to the question that might me important

Answer (score 0):

The two other answers are right, I'd change the data though:

```
"boats": [
    {
        "id": "637",
        "name": " Subcat 1",
        "translations": null
    },
    {
        "id": "638",
        "name": "Subcat 2",
        "translations": null
    }
],
```

Using the id as key and then giving the containing object a "id" property is kinda pointless. When you change the data to this structure your code will work fine.

Comment: I've added a note to the question that might me important

Comment: Still same answer. :)

Comment: Can't change the data structure because I won't have access to that

Answer (score 0):

Besides all other answers that already correctly point to `obj.boats` being an `Object` and not an `Array`, I'd like providing a solution that demonstrates the elegant beauty of `Array.reduce` ...

```js
var boatChartData = [{
  "id": "622",
  "name": "some name",
  "boats": {
    "637": {
      "id": "637",
      "name": "Subcat 1",
      "translations": null
    },
    "638": {
      "id": "638",
      "name": "Subcat 2",
      "translations": null
    }
  },
  "image": "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6286b"
}, {
  "id": "623",
  "name": "other name",
  "boats": {
    "639": {
      "id": "639",
      "name": "Supercat",
      "translations": null
    },
    "640": {
      "id": "640",
      "name": "Supercat II",
      "translations": null
    },
    "641": {
      "id": "641",
      "name": "Supercat III",
      "translations": null
    }
  },
  "image": "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6295c"
}];


function collectBoatChartData(collector, chartItem/*, idx, list*/) {
  var
    boatNameList,
    boatMap = chartItem.boats;

  if (boatMap != null) {
    collector.chartItemTitleList.push([

      chartItem.name,
      " [",
      chartItem.id,
      "]"

    ].join(""));

    boatNameList = Object.keys(boatMap).map(collector.getBoatNameByKey, boatMap);

    collector.boatNameList = collector.boatNameList.concat(boatNameList);

  //collector.chartItemBoatNameList.push(boatNameList);
    collector.chartItemBoatCountList.push(boatNameList.length);
  }
  return collector;
}


var processedBoatChartData = boatChartData.reduce(collectBoatChartData, {

  getBoatNameByKey: function (key) {
    return this[key].name;
  },
  boatNameList: [],
  chartItemTitleList: [],
//chartItemBoatNameList: [],
  chartItemBoatCountList: []
});

console.log("processedBoatChartData.boatNameList : ", processedBoatChartData.boatNameList);
console.log("processedBoatChartData.chartItemTitleList : ", processedBoatChartData.chartItemTitleList);
  //console.log("processedBoatChartData.chartItemBoatNameList : ", processedBoatChartData.chartItemBoatNameList);
console.log("processedBoatChartData.chartItemBoatCountList : ", processedBoatChartData.chartItemBoatCountList);
```

**Note**

Taking into account the OP's additional comment, mentioning the provided axample's real data structure, the above provided solution of mine just changes to ...

```
var boatChartData = {
  "id": "622",
  "name": "some name",
  "boats": {
    "637": {
      "id": "637",
      "name": "Subcat 1",
      "translations": null
    },
    "638": {
      "id": "638",
      "name": "Subcat 2",
      "translations": null
    }
  },
  "image": "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6286b"
};

var processedBoatChartData = [boatChartData].reduce(collectBoatChartData, {

  getBoatNameByKey: function (key) {
    return this[key].name;
  },
  boatNameList: [],
  chartItemTitleList: [],
//chartItemBoatNameList: [],
  chartItemBoatCountList: []
});
```

.., proving that generic solutions can be recycled/adapted easily, if e.g. data structures do change.